# Custom url with firebase cloud function with nginx reverse proxy?

Tags: firebase, nginx, google-cloud-functions, nginx-reverse-proxy

Right now I have develop cloud function with firebase and after deploy I just get the endpoint something like this

```
https://us-central1-app-id.cloudfunctions.net/api/path/of/api/
```

my question is, is it possible to map custom domain with this endpoint by using nginx proxy like

```
http://my-domain.com/path/of/api/
```

After some experiment I just got this error after link my custom domain to cloud function

```
404. That’s an error.

The requested URL /path/of/api/ was not found on this server. That’s all we know.
```

Here is my config on nginx

```
  location /path/of/api/ {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Keep-Alive";
    proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection "Keep-Alive";
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_pass https://us-central1-app-id.cloudfunctions.net/api;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the `Host` to `us-central1-app-id.cloudfunctions.net`, for example in your config:

```
proxy_set_header Host us-central1-app-id.cloudfunctions.net;
```

Answer (score -2):

You probably don't need any NGINX proxy to perform URL routing. You can simply create a firebase hosting project and use the rewrite rules for invoking your cloud functions. I have written in depth about this topic on my blog, have a look.

https://blog.emad.in/firebase-cloud-functions-with-nginx-like-reverse-proxy/